# Bluetooth iOS Background Mode for Only Some Users

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I would like my app to advertise (i.e. transmit via bluetooth) when the app is in background, but only for certain key users.  When I put the required bluetooth-peripheral key in my plist, it causes every single user to be alerted that the app requires the ability to transmit data to other devices via bluetooth, rather than just the users who need that ability.  The alert may be off-putting for the vast majority of users who do not need the ability.  I can check programmatically if the user is a key user, but how do I programmatically request the ability to run bluetooth in background only if the user is a key user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other services such as location or notifications where the permission request is triggered by code, the Bluetooth permission request is triggered by the background entitlement, presumably because the request can't be made at the point where the functionality is used as the app is in the background at that point.